# Changing Outline/Border of Jquery mobile element

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change the default sky blue outline color to green of some Jquery mobile elements like  and input
[image]

I want same glowing border but in green color 
Here is what i have tried on `onfocus` event

```
function add_green_border(x)
{
x.style.outline = "1px solid green";    
}
```

but its not working..

Here is the **Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/SaXYL/1/

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to solve the problem? If you can post your code into a fiddle, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Jason: fiddle posted....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
.ui-focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px green;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/Lf66a/1/

Comment: it worked. thanks  :-) but how can i show it on onclick like this scenario "when selected value is default show red shadow" here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lf66a/5/

Comment: the problem is that i have to change these colors on different events like onfocus onclick etc...